# How to change a date's format?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to change date format from `08/10/2015` to `2015-10-08`

I have tried following code but not working for me.

```
    $startDate = $this->input->post('startDate');//08/10/2015
    $startDateFormat = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($startDate));
    $endDate = $this->input->post('endDate');//09/10/2015
    $endDateFormat = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($endDate));
```

Comment: Use `$startDate = "08/10/2015;"`

Comment: What error do you have ? Everything seems correct. Try to echo everything and see what's wrong. Or echo `gettype`

Comment: this is the date format I am getting 1969-12-31

Comment: @John Conde  this is not duplicate question please look both the questions

Comment: Are you serious? It's an *exact* duplicate.

Comment: With  `$startDateFormat =  $startDate -> format('Y-m-d');` ?

Comment: If it's not a string why using `strtodate` ?

Comment: Okay thanks for your support it works finally.

Comment: $date = new DateTime($this->input->post('startDate'));
  $startDateFormat = $date->format('Y-m-d');
  //$startDateFormat = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($startDate));
  $endDate = new DateTime($this->input->post('endDate'));
  $endDateFormat = $date->format('Y-m-d');